# How to manually trigger ssh add dialog box?

Tags: ssh, gnome-keyring, ssh-agent

Running `ssh-add` at the command line no longer unlocks the ssh keys properly on my system (Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity). Even after I've run ssh-add, when I ssh to a server, I get a dialog box popping up to ask me for my ssh key passphrase. After that things work as expected.

`ssh-agent` is running. When I first log in:

```
$ ps -ef | grep ssh-agent
mish      1853  1818  0 18:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/gnome-session --session=ubuntu
```

How can I unlock the ssh key properly without having to ssh to a server? (Manually triggering the ssh key dialog window would be OK as a solution, but I don't know how to do that).

My use case is that I use [tmuxinator](https://github.com/aziz/tmuxinator) and want to set up multiple ssh connections. So I want the ssh key unlocked. Otherwise all the ssh key dialog boxes all pop up and I have to enter my passphrase multiple times. Or I can ssh somewhere before launching tmuxinator, but the connection is slow here, so that just adds friction. So I want to unlock the ssh key before launching tmuxinator, without having to ssh somewhere first.

### Edit

Just tried logging out and logging back in again. Then I did:

```
$ env | grep -i ssh
SSH_AGENT_PID=8693
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-Ho4cfE/ssh
$ ssh-add -D
All identities removed.
$ ssh-add -l
1024 b8:12:34:56[...]:19 name@computer (DSA)
$ ssh-add
Enter passphrase for /home/name/.ssh/id_dsa: 
Identity added: /home/name/.ssh/id_dsa (/home/mish/.ssh/id_dsa)
$ ssh-add -l
1024 b8:12:34:56[...]:19 /home/name/.ssh/id_dsa (DSA)
1024 b8:12:34:56[...]:19 name@computer (DSA)
0 mish@mishtop:~$ ssh server
```

At which point I am again asked for my passphrase by the GUI dialog box. Frustrating ...

It's also interesting that after "All identities removed" that `ssh-add -l` still shows an identity. That confuses me. And there does only appear to be one ssh-agent running.

### Edit 2:

I found a bug on launchpad about this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/841672

However this question was about finding a workaround rather than asking why it didn't work, so I hope the question can stand.

### Edit 3:

Nothing unusual in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` - I haven't touched it. I do have a `~/.ssh/config` but that is just ports and usernames.

I watched what processes were running when the dialog popped up, and it was `/usr/lib/gnome-keyring/gnome-keyring-prompt-3`, launched by `/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login` I tried launching the prompt from a terminal but nothing happened. So still stuck.

Comment: I assume there's no ssh-agent running. Is an agent installed? If yes, can you start it manually? Does it emit  any errors on startup? If there are no errors, the next step would be trying to "autostart" it on login.

Comment: @tohuwawohu: the standard ssh-agent is running. I'll update the question to make that clear.

Comment: Really strange. Maybe any weird SSH config option? Is there anything unusual in `/etc/ssh/ssh/ssh_config`?

Comment: Maybe this thread has the answer (or at least a workaround) - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1868194 - I'll try it soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a direct answer to the above question, but a work around for the core problem:

Stop gnome-keyring ssh-agent from starting. Then ssh-agent, ssh-add and ssh works as expected. (Or at least as I expect).

To stop gnome-keyring ssh-agent from starting do:

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop.disabled
```

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

This does launch a graphical prompt for my ssh password, but a different one to the one that actually allows ssh to use the ssh key. Even after I've done this, I still get a GUI prompt popping up to ask for my ssh key passphrase :/

See Edit 3 in the question above for more.

### Original

I found a way to trigger it in the end. I created `~/bin/gssh-add` and put the following in it:

```
SSH_ASK_PASS=/usr/bin/ssh-askpass ssh-add
```

I then make it executable:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/gssh-add
```

And then I launch it using Alt+F2. That triggers the gnome dialog box.

Note that if you run `gssh-add` from the terminal it will not trigger the gnome dialog box. See the [ENVIRONMENT section of the ssh-add man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/ssh-add.1.html#contenttoc3) for details as to why.

Answer (score 0):

> Or I can ssh somewhere before launching tmuxinator, but the connection is slow here, so that just adds friction.

Don't forget that your '*somewhere*' need not be remote:

```
ssh localhost
```

That's how I usually do it.

(I then type `^D` at the new shell prompt to throw it away and drop back to my old one.  If you don't mind the extra keystrokes, a command like `ssh localhost true` is a tidier alternative.)

Of course, this only works on systems that request SSH keys (e.g. after using `ssh-copy-id`), but from your question it sounds like you've probably got that already.